# How to store text as paragraphs in SQLite database in a iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, sqlite

In my iPhone app, I have a requirement to store a huge amount of text. I have paragraphs of text to be stored in my database along with the newline characters.

What should I do to store the text as paragraphs in SQLite database?

For example, I want to store paragraphs like the ones below in:

> (the mother of the faithful believers) The commencement of the Divine Inspiration to Allah's Apostle was in the form of good dreams which came true like bright day light, and then the love of seclusion was bestowed upon him. He used to go in seclusion in the cave of Hira where he used to worship (Allah alone) continuously for many days before his desire to see his family. He used to take with him the journey food for the stay and then come back to (his wife) Khadija to take his food like-wise again till suddenly the Truth descended upon him while he was in the cave of Hira. The angel came to him and asked him to read. The Prophet replied, "I do not know how to read.
>
> The Prophet added, "The angel caught me (forcefully) and pressed me so hard that I could not bear it any more. He then released me and again asked me to read and I replied, 'I do not know how to read.'

Basically I want to save the paragraphs in database in the same format with carriage returns.

Comment: What part do you need help with? The sqlite setup? The column type? Or the redisplay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by *huge* and how you're planning on showing the data.  The SQLite TEXT field, by default, can store 1 billion bytes.

You could in theory store all of it in a TEXT field in SQLite, then render it in a UIScrollView (or whatever it is you're using to render) and check the performance, memory usage, etc.

If the performance is unacceptable, you can try "chunking" the text into multiple rows and displaying only the records of the text required for the UI.

See the [SQLite Limits document](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html):

**Maximum length of a string or BLOB**

> ```
> The maximum number of bytes in a string or BLOB in SQLite is defined by
> ```
>
> the preprocessor macro
>   SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH. The default value
>   of this macro is 1 billion (1 thousand
>   million or 1,000,000,000). You can
>   raise or lower this value at
>   compile-time using a command-line
>   option like this:
>
> ```
> -DSQLITE_MAX_LENGTH=123456789
> ```

Answer (score 2):

On the face of it, SQLite doesn't treat newlines any differently than other characters;  you can just store the test as-is.

The issue, though, is why are you storing large volumes of raw text in SQLite?  If you want to search it or organize it somehow, SQLite (nor Core Data) is probably not the best choice without first massaging the text into some other form.  Or, alternatively, you'd want to store the raw text on disk then keep some kind of searchable index in the database.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be if you want to display your text in a webview then add HTML tags to your text.So in that way you can add paragraphs,New lines and many other effects to your text.

Thanks

Comment: Korde: Thanks for your input. No, I want to display the text in text view. What should I do?

Comment: If you want to display the text in a text view then its a bit tricky.I would suggest go for WebView as it would give you more flexibility and ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

so do you want to split the text into paragraph and store each in its own row like:

```
(paragraph_number, text_of_paragraph)
```

that would be:

```
create table paragraphs (paragraph_number, text_of_paragraph);
```

then in what ever language you use split the text into a list of (pn, tp) named l and do like:

```
executemany("insert into paragraphs values (?, ?)", l)
```

or do like:

```
for p in l:
    execute("insert into paragraphs values (?, ?)", p)
```

Comment: I have huge amount of text. Many Chapters and many pages of text into each chapter. So i suppose storing data as you said wont be much efficient for me. Anyways thanks for your help and support. If you have a more efficient way of doing it then please let me know

Comment: even if you have a few GB of text using this scheme would let you locate a paragraph by it's number which doesn't have to be a single value it could be a tuple of locators, and even Wikipedia stores their text in a database and their full history compressed is over 30GB

Answer (score 0):

i would use HTML to represent my paragraphs (i.e)

#### Saving the Text

```
 <div>
 <p>(the mother of the faithful believers) The commencement of the Divine Inspiration to Allah's Apostle was in the form of good dreams which came true    like bright day light, and then the love of seclusion was bestowed upon him. He used to go in seclusion in the cave of Hira where he used to worship (Allah alone) continuously for many days before his desire to see his family. He used to take with him the journey food for the stay and then come back to (his wife) Khadija to take his food like-wise again till suddenly the Truth descended upon him while he was in the cave of Hira. The angel came to him and asked him to read. The Prophet replied, "I do not know how to read.</p>
 <p>The Prophet added, "The angel caught me (forcefully) and pressed me so hard that I could not bear it any more. He then released me and again asked me to read and I replied, 'I do not know how to read.</p>
</div>
```

#### Loading the Paragraphs

I would load them inside a UIWebView as html, you can save the HTML into a file in the app sandbox let's say Paragraph1.HTML load it as the following:

```
// this is a user defined method
 -(void)loadDocument:(NSString*)documentName inView:(UIWebView*)webView
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:sFilePath];// Path of the HTML File
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [web loadRequest:request];
}
```

dispose the File after loading it, this will save you much time and space.
Good luck.